# How to efficiently implement the following code in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

```
M=50
G= randi(100,100,2);
N = 100;
iS = zeros(M,M);
for i1 = 1:M
  for i2 = 1:M
      if i1 == i2
          for g = 1:N
              iS(i1,i2) = iS(i1,i2) + eq(i1,G(g,1))+eq(i2,G(g,2));
          end
      else
          for g = 1:N
              iS(i1,i2) = iS(i1,i2)-(eq(i1,G(g,1))*eq(i2,G(g,2))+eq(i1,G(g,2))*eq(i2,G(g,1)));
          end
      end
          
  end 
end
```

I am trying to implement this code efficiently in MATLAB. The run time seems to take too much time. Is there a way to implement this code efficiently?

G is a 1000*2 double array.

Comment: Please read [mre], then [edit] your question accordingly. Tty to make a small example for your arrays `G`, `eq`, etc. Also, if `M` is an array, as you say, then `for i1=1:M` makes no sense. Did you [preallocate](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have made the changes.

Comment: So `eq` is the MATLAB function for `==`? I thought it would be an array of some sort. Is `iS` initialized to zero before the loop?

Comment: it is equivalent to 'kroneckerDelta' but when using numbers. 

Yes

Comment: Ive made the changes

Comment: I ran your code, changing G to be 1000x2 as you say you have in real life, and it took 0.02s. This is MATLAB R2017a, it could be faster in newer versions. Not sure why you say this is taking too much time. It is easy to remove the inner loop, but the runtime changed from 0.0200 s to 0.0188 s, not really worth the effort. Removing the other loops would require large intermediate arrays, which will make your code slower. Unless you're actually using Octave, not MATLAB, then this question is moot. If you're using Octave, please tag accordingly.

Comment: @Cris I get 0.025 in 2020b, the strange thing is that even removing the inner loops slows it down by 0.002~4 s. It's only two weeks that I've upgraded from 2016a and everyone kept saying that MATLAB has optimized for loops since, but I couldn't even imagine that.

Comment: @saastn: Removing the inner loops slows it down a bit for me too with N=100, but when it's 1000 as OP's real matrix `G` is, then it's a bit faster. --- Things have improved a bit since R2016a, but the real big change happened in R13 (2002), with the first JIT, and then again in R2015b with the all-new JIT. Each of these releases had a huge jump in execution speed. Other releases have seen smaller changes, or important changes to very specific bits of syntax. https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/02/12/run-code-faster-with-the-new-matlab-execution-engine/

Answer (score 1):

The loop can be reduced to the following vectorized form. Note that it uses matrix multiplication to speed up the calculation.

```
i1 = 1:M;
i2 = 1:M;
iS = -((i1 == G(:, 1)).' * (i2 == G(:, 2)) + (i1 == G(:, 2)).' * (i2 == G(:, 1)));
iS(1:M+1:end) = sum(i1 == G(:, 1)) + sum(i2 == G(:, 2));
```

For the last part you can also use [`histcounts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html):

```
i1 = 1:M;
i2 = 1:M;
iS = -((i1 == G(:, 1)).' * (i2 == G(:, 2)) + (i1 == G(:, 2)).' * (i2 == G(:, 1)));
iS(1:M+1:end) = histcounts(G(:, 1), 1:M+1) + histcounts(G(:, 2), 1:M+1);
```